# How to get all values in a specific property within a list of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like this:

```
var array = [{name:"AName1", value: 1},{name:"AName2", value: 2}, ...];
```

How do I get all the values from a specific property? Say, I want to get all the names from every object in the array, creating a new array with those names ["AName1, "AName2", ...]

I've tried to use _.pick from underscore.js:

```
var result = _.map(array, function (current) {
    return _.pick(current, 'Name');
});
```

but it creates another array of objects with only the name property, which is not what i want to do

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

Comment: why not just iterate over array items, and for each item push the name property value to another array: `if(item.name) { result.push( item.name ); }`

Comment: `array.map(function(obj){ return {name: obj.name}; })`

Comment: Thanks, I don't know what i was thinking, this worked for me: `array.map(function(item){ return item.name; });`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) like this:

```
array.map(function(item){ return item.name; });
```

> The `map()` method creates a new array with the results of calling a
>   provided function on every element in this array.